# Деление на 0 в калькуляторе

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу ввести функцию "Если выполняется деление и второе число равно 0, необходимо выводить строку "Деление на 0!".Много вариантов опробовал,можете предложить альтернативу?

```
first = float(input())
second = float(input())
operation = input("Введите название операции или символ")

if operation == "+":
    answer = first + second
    
elif operation == "-":
    answer = first - second

elif operation == "/" and second !=0:
    if second == 0:
        print("Деление на 0!")
        break
        
elif operation == "*":
    answer = first * second 

elif operation == "mod":
    answer = first % second 
        
elif operation == "pow":
    answer = first ** second

elif operation == "div":
    answer = first // second
  
print(answer)
```

Comment: А чем не угодил элементарнейший вариант `answer = "Деление на 0!"`?

Comment: и правда, зачем изобретать велосипед, просто в ответ выводите "деление на 0!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если пойти дальше в улучшении логики, то можно сделать ещё пару улучшений.

Во-первых, ошибку деления на ноль в Питоне можно обрабатывать проще – операторы деления генерируют исключение вида [`ZeroDivisionError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ZeroDivisionError), которое можно ловить глобально, а не в конкретные операциях.

Во-вторых, здесь не хватает инкапсуляции. Вы хотели использовать `break`, видимо, подразумевая `return`, но для него нужно выполнение кода в контексте функции – создадим её. Это полезно ещё и тем, что позволит переиспользовать код. Также, хорошо бы что-то выводить при получении неизвестной операции.

```py
def calculate_inner(first, second, operation):
    if operation == "+":
        return first + second

    if operation == "-":
        return first - second

    if operation == "/":
        return first / second

    if operation == "*":
        return first * second 

    if operation == "mod":
        return first % second 

    if operation == "pow":
        return first ** second

    if operation == "div":
        return first // second

    return "Неизвестная операция \"%s\"" % operation


def calculate(first, second, operation):
    try:
        return calculate_inner(first, second, operation)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return "Деление на 0"


first = float(input())
second = float(input())
operation = input("Введите название операции или символ")

print(calculate(first, second, operation))
```

---

Помимо этого, можно вынести код операций в отдельные функции/лямбы и положить их в словарик. Это особенно удобно когда код операций большой и нагромождение их всех в одной функции выглядит слишком загруженно. Также это позволит легко создавать несколько имён одним и тем же операциям. Ещё можно использовать модуль [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) со встроенными операторами Питона в виде функций. В итоге код получится и лаконичным, и удобным для дальнейших улучшений (например, можно сделать отдельный словарь операций для функций от одного аргумента вроде взятия модуля, тригонометрических функций и что угодно ещё).

```py
import operator as OP

OPERATIONS = {}
OPERATIONS["+"]   = lambda a, b: a+b  # можно лямбдой
OPERATIONS["+"]   = OP.add
OPERATIONS["-"]   = OP.sub
OPERATIONS["*"]   = OP.mul
OPERATIONS["/"]   = OP.truediv
OPERATIONS["mod"] = OP.mod
OPERATIONS["%"]   = OP.mod
OPERATIONS["pow"] = OP.pow
OPERATIONS["**"]  = OP.pow
OPERATIONS["div"] = OP.floordiv
OPERATIONS["//"]  = OP.floordiv


def calculate(first, second, operation):
    try:
        return OPERATIONS[operation](first, second)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return "Деление на 0"
    except KeyError:
        return "Неизвестная операция \"%s\"" % operation
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну можно просто отлавливать ошибку и передавать в переменную, которая отвечает за значение, что будет выведено, сообщение типа `Деление на 0!`

Реализация:

```py
first = float(input('Первое число: '))
second = float(input('Второе число: '))
operation = input("Введите название операции или символ: ")

if operation == "/":
  try:
    answer = first / second
  except ZeroDivisionError:
    answer = "Деление на 0!"

print(answer)
```

Comment: Только начал изучать синтаксис данного языка,пока не знаю о данных операторах,но спасибо большое,буду знать!!!

Answer (score 1):

Рассмотрим Ваш код:

```py
elif operation == "/" and second != 0:
    # С точки зрения архитектуры плохо смешивать логику
    # проверки типа операции и её аргументов в одном месте

    # second здесь не может быть равен нулю,
    # т.к условие выше это отсекло.
    if second == 0:
        print("Деление на 0!")
        break  # break вне циклов while/for не используется
```

Вот простейший рабочий вариант:

```py
elif operation == "/":
    if second == 0:
        print("Деление на 0!")
    else:
        answer = first / second
```

Аналогично делаем для `div`, `mod`. Чтобы строку ошибки не дублировать, лучше её вынести в отдельную константу `ZERO_DIV_ERROR`.

Comment: Выражаю огромную благодарность,за такой развернутый ответ,так глубоко пока что я не продвинулся,но очень интересно будет это изучить.Можете посоветовать : как лучше изучать пайтон(книги по пайтону, алгоритмам, образовательные сайты по типу stepik ?

Comment: @DustySosalex лично я книг по программированию не читал  Мне и многим знакомым всегда было проще брать конкретные задачи, искать варианты их решения, гуглить и разбирать отдельные статьи по нужным темам, примеры (например, смотреть топовые ответы по изучаемым темам на этом сайте) и крупных проектов (GitHub). Книги игнорить не надо конечно, просто должны быть постоянное впитывание информации из разных источников и особенно постоянная практика.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно будет проще через обработку исключений с использованием конструкции try…except.

Для этого надо поместить код (в котором как вы предполагаете может быть деление на 0) между операторами try и except (см. пример ниже).

В начале будет выполняться код, размещенный между данными операторами. В случае если в ходе выполнения этого кода будет ошибка ZeroDivisionError: (деление на 0), то будет выполняться код из блока except

Comment: Такой ответ тут уже есть: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1130076/260769 Хотя там не так подробно словами описано, но там вместо этого приведён собственно код плюс краткое описание.

Comment: Согласен. Ответил с ходу. Не изучил другие ответы

Comment: Ситуация в общем типичная для начинающих, впредь будете читать комментарии и ответы )